# Is it possible to remove sugar from a sweetened drink but without boiling it?

Tags: solutions

Is it possible to remove sugar from a sweetened drink without boiling it? This might not be a good question but I'm wondering if you could separate sugar from a sweetened drink and replace the sugar for an artificial sweetener.

Comment: Not by an easy, fast nor cheap way, and you would not probably want to drink it afterwards. Focus rather on non sweetened drinks.

Comment: Any drink specifically? Many commercial beverages have **added sugar**.

Comment: Basically no. There is no simple way of doing this. Much much easier to make the drink with artificial sweetener from the beginning.